# Can't able to install Debian Package in Kali Linux?

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, repository

I am trying to intall some third party softwares in kali but i get error all time when i try to install by using Terminal ?

```
sudo dpkg -i /root/Desktop/gdebi_0.9.5.5+nmu1_all.deb

(Reading database ... 319034 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gdebi_0.9.5.5+nmu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking gdebi (0.9.5.5+nmu1) over (0.9.5.5+nmu1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gdebi:
gdebi depends on gdebi-core (= 0.9.5.5+nmu1); however:
Package gdebi-core is not installed.
gdebi depends on gir1.2-vte-2.90; however:
Package gir1.2-vte-2.90 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package gdebi (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-9) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
gdebi
```

what should i do now ?
Please help me with this. **Any Answers are highly appreciated**

but when try to add missing dependencies using this i get this error ?

```
apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
gdebi gdebi-core libappindicator1 libdbusmenu-glib4 libdbusmenu-gtk4
libindicator7
Recommended packages:
lintian
The following packages will be REMOVED:
picasa
The following NEW packages will be installed:
gdebi-core libappindicator1 libdbusmenu-glib4 libdbusmenu-gtk4   
               libindicator7
The following packages will be upgraded:
gdebi
1 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 329 kB/382 kB of archives.
After this operation, 108 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libdbusmenu-glib4
    amd64 16.04.1+17.04.20170109.1-4
404  Not Found
Err:2 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libdbusmenu-gtk4   
amd64 16.04.1+17.04.20170109.1-4
404  Not Found
Err:3 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libappindicator1      

amd64 0.4.92-4
404  Not Found
Err:4 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 gdebi all    

0.9.5.7+nmu1
404  Not Found
Err:5 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 gdebi-core all   

0.9.5.7+nmu1
404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/libd/libdbusmenu   

/libdbusmenu-glib4_16.04.1+17.04.20170109.1-4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/libd/libdbusmenu 

/libdbusmenu-gtk4_16.04.1+17.04.20170109.1-4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/liba  

/libappindicator/libappindicator1_0.4.92-4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/g/gdebi 

/gdebi_0.9.5.7+nmu1_all.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/g/gdebi/gdebi-  

core_0.9.5.7+nmu1_all.deb  404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with   

--fix-missing?
```

Comment: @dsstorefile get this error **above in question** when i use apt-get -f install

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error messages that you are getting.

The package that you are trying to install has dependencies which you also need to install. You can do that by installing the package with `apt-get`

For the error that you are seeing with `apt-get`, your `/etc/apt/sources.list` needs to be corrected. The file should read:

`deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib`

Once you have that, go to the location of the `.deb` package that you are trying to install and:

`apt-get install gdebi_0.9.5.5+nmu1_all.deb`

If you obtained that package outside of the repository and the dependencies don't exist then you'll have to download them separately, put them into a directory, and then `apt-get install *.deb` inside the directory.

Comment: get error above in question when i use apt-get -f install

Comment: See the update in my answer

Comment: Just to ask, what are you doing with Kali Linux? Not to be condescending but if you don't how to use `apt-get` to install packages or how to configure repositories then you're going to have quite a difficult time using Kali because it's designed for users who have an advanced understanding of Linux. If you just want a distro for a workstation then it's better to use Ubuntu, Mint, or Debian.